# When I update a table in Microsoft Visual Studio, it gets stuck at Preparing update script... forever

Tags: database, visual-studio

I am a student and my assignment is to create a database with a couple simple tables. But when I update one of them, I can no longer update it again or update any other tables because I get stuck in the Preview Database Updates window, where the text says Preparing update script... forever until I click cancel. How can I fix it so I can update and create table's.

Comment: Hi can you include the version of tools, visual studio, database, and the tables you have created, this will make it easier for someone to help you

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.2 in an asp.net Core Web App project. The bug is as simple as, if you open the Preview Database Updates window a second time, regardless of what option you took the first time, it will get stuck in an never ending "Preparing update script...". Only thing I can do is restart Visual Studio and reopen it. This happens even for a fresh project. The database is a local database.

Answer (score 4):

I met the same issue. I usually do the following to solve the problem(or bug?):

1. Restart vs
2. Restart the SQL service
3. Close database connections and refresh

But as Marc Pilgaard said, second time always stuck, so I suggest using the SSMS(Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same situation just occur where the Update wouldn't progress. I followed Dicken Jone's advice above and started by closing the database connections and refresh. That didn't work, so I saved and restarted Visual Studio. I went to create a new table and update it and it worked just fine.

Comment: This is more of a comment than a separate answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30941688)

Answer (score 0):

Disconnecting and connecting again in the DB browser window helps

Answer (score 0):

If using a .mdf, then you should try:

solution explorer > right click on .mdf > detach > refresh > update database

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and none of the proposed solutions worked. I fixed it with a Repair of Visual Studio 2022 from Visual Studio Installer.